# Vb.NET - Transparent elements in User Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

Does anybody know why this happens?
I've a TabControl where I insert UserControls but all the elements with white background create a hole in the WinForm and I can see the desktop...

[image]

The only way I find is to change Background color of elements but in some Element I've some visual bug.

Comment: Check the `TransparencyKey` value

Comment: Thank you a lot... it's so easy but i'm new. Sorry for stupid question